# Getting error while login to mysql

Tags: mysql

I am not able to login mysql 
mysql -uroot -p
-nologin: mysql: not found [No such file or directory]

while mysql is running and socket file is also there

SUCCESS! MySQL running (7932)
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 23  2015 //opt/app/mysql/mysql.sock

please help me on this

Comment: you need to change current path to where your mysql binary resides - it can't be found now.

Comment: For Mac: Try adding this export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/ to your .profile file

Comment: is it reason of mysql binary is missing